# Inherited class and parent's constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#define PI 3.14
using  namespace std;

    class ellipse 
    {
          protected:
          float a,b;

          public:
            ellipse(float x, float y) 
                {
                a=x;
                b=y;
                }

                 float area()
                 {
                 return (PI*a*b);
                 }
  };

  class circle : public ellipse 
  {
     public:
        circle(float r) 
         {
            a=r;
            b=r;
         }
  };

main() {
    float x,y,r;
    cout<<"Enter the two axes of the ellipse (eg. 5 4) : ";
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<"\nEnter the radius of the circle : ";
    cin>>r;
    ellipse obj(x,y);
    cout<<"\nEllipse Area : "<<obj.area();
    circle obj1(r);
    cout<<"\nCircle Area : "<<obj1.area();
}
```

When I compiled this program I got the follwing errors:

```
friendclass4.cpp: In constructor ‘circle::circle(float)’:
friendclass4.cpp:24:1: error: no matching function for call to ‘ellipse::ellipse()’
friendclass4.cpp:24:1: note: candidates are:
friendclass4.cpp:10:1: note: ellipse::ellipse(float, float)
friendclass4.cpp:10:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
friendclass4.cpp:5:7: note: ellipse::ellipse(const ellipse&)
friendclass4.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I added a second constructor for ellipse as shown below (trial and error) and solved the issue

```
ellipse() {

}
```

But I am not sure why the errors occurred before adding this.
Could anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Have you heard of Circle-ellipse problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor `circle(float)`, it needs to call the default constructor `ellipse()` with no arguments, because you did not provide any arguments in the "initialization list."  To fix it, do this (and remove your `ellipse()` default constructor):

```
circle(float r)
  : ellipse(r, r)
{
}
```

This simply delegates the initialization of `a` and `b` to the two-argument `ellipse` constructor.  It offers better encapsulation and more concise code.

Comment: Am I right in saying this : Though the parent class' constructor is not inherited it will be called when a child class is instantiated.

Comment: It is true that constructors are not exactly inherited: the presence of a constructor taking two `float`s in the base class does not imply one exists in the derived class.  But the derived class can call any public or protected base class constructors, and when a derived instance is created, it *must* call one base class constructor.  By default, it will call the "default constructor" of the base class, which is the one taking no arguments.  But you can call any base class constructor, including protected ones which are not available to the outside world.